# htaccess: how to get cpanel username out of url and redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following htaccess lines...

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ index.php?p1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^~([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ ~$1/index.php?p1=$2 [L]
```

The first line works fine, its the second line that doesn't work at all...

The first line does this....
domain.com/about -> domain.com/index.php?p1=about

What I'm trying to do with the second line...
if the url is   server1.domain.com/~username/about....
I need it to translate to   server1.domain.com/~username/index.php?p1=about

Basically, detecting if there is a ~

I am trying to work out my code to allow for the development url of the hostname/~username

Right now it is showing the green apache 404 not found page when trying to visit the website using that code.

Please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: Is there any .htaccess in `~/username/` directory as well?

Comment: it isnt a directory.  It is how apache writes direct access to user accounts in cPanel.    server1.domain.com/~username/  loads website at usernamedomain.com

Comment: In any unix `~username/` always means a directory that means user's home directory.

Comment: if that means the users home directory, that means that my .htaccess file in that directory should load right?  And I knew that, I just meant there is no directory before user home directory.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `there is no directory before user home directory` But in any case your 2nd rule is not working because if is probably in wrong place. It should be placed directly in the `~username/.htaccess` OR else in Apache httpd.conf.

Comment: it is in document root of the username.  I havent' added any other htaccess files.     ~username/.htaccess (public_html/.htaccess).  How would I go about adding it to Apache's httpd.conf?

Comment: If you have access to server config then add 2nd rule in in `<Directory>` section of your default site. You can find several examples online for that.

Comment: Do I just copy and paste it into the httpd.conf inside <directory> or is there a certain format?  Any way you can show me that format?  If you do it as an answer, and it works, then i'll accept the answer.

Comment: Just came back online and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the order of the rules and add a `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^~([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ ~$1/index.php?p1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ index.php?p1=$1 [L]
```

You need to be sure that this `.htaccess` file is triggered both on requests to pages from `domain.com` and pages from `server1.domain.com`.

Also, if you have a `.htaccess` file in any subdirectories (you shouldn't, based on your problem description), you will have to modify those accordingly, but we would need more information.

Comment: I only have 1 htaccess file.  The file works great except when i tried using it with ~username.  What does the `RewriteBase /` do?  I had the order switched before and it still didnt work.  Is that what the `RewriteBase /` is for?

Comment: I added the code above...it doesn't work.  Here's my setup:  I installed cPanel on the dedicated server.  I added an account.  I modified the .htaccess file(public_html/.htaccess) that this is in in that account.  that is all I have done to the server as far as htaccess is concerned.

Comment: @anubhava's comments are on-point.  The issue is where your `.htaccess` file is; it isn't being processed.

Comment: it processes just fine when I go to website.com/about    but not when i go to server.domain.com/~website/about .  The htaccess file is in the web root directory (public_html) of the user.  Where do I need to modify to achieve my goal?

Comment: When you say it's in the web root directory, is it in, for example, `/home/joebob/public_html/`?  That's where it needs to be.  Depending on your server configuration, though, it may not be able to find the `index.php`.  What happens if you put the file in the correct directory and replace `index.php?p1=$1` with `http://google.com/` -- does the redirect happen?

Comment: it is in /home/user/public_html yes.  The only redirect i have that is anythign related to this was in my example.

Comment: I understand that. I'm saying, replace `index.php?p1=$1` with `http://google.com/` and report back on what happens.  The question right now is: is the server even looking at that `.htaccess` file when someone requests `http://server1.domain.com/~username/about`?

Comment: it still goes to 404 not found.

Comment: Final question: what if you put a simple index.php in the user's home directory and request it, like `http://server1.domain.com/~username/index.php`? If that loads, we have a redirect problem. If it doesn't load -- and I'm suspecting it will not -- then you have a problem that has less to do with `.htaccess` than with `httpd.conf` (see this page http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/howto/public_html.html).

Comment: I can load index.php using server1.domain.com/~username

Comment: I can load anything on the server that way...its /about and /blahblahblah that it doesn't understand dealing with htaccess.

Comment: Take a look at [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase). You need to do something similar, so that Apache understands to treat `/~username` the same as `/` when necessary.

Comment: You were almost right.  So you get the answer with an explanation of what was wrong with your answer.  1) Rewrite base ended up needing to be `/~username`.  This allows the htaccess rewrites to work with domain or hostname/~username   .... then, I ended up just using anubhava's rewrite because i already had it in the file. `RewriteRule ^/?(~[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /$1/index.php?p1=$2 [L,QSA]`.  I contacted cPanel and they did not recommend me using this rewrite inside httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

You need to place this rule in your `httpd.conf`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?(~[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /$1/index.php?p1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And make sure this line is uncommented in `httpd.conf`:

```
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
```

Then make sure `index.php` is present directly under `~username/`

Comment: Thank you, I will update my files and let you know the outcome ASAP.  It will probably be a couple of hours before I have a chance to work on it.

Comment: I tried this..it didn't work right.  Also, contacted cPanel about this...and they said they wouldn't recommend adding a rewrite like this inside httpd.conf.  They actually were able to get it working, but inside normal htaccess and just adding the correct RewriteBase `/~username`.  Thank you for taking the time to help though.  I did end up using your rewrite rule, +1 for that!